# Updates fail due to "/etc/default/grub: splash”: not found" error 

Tags: grub2, kernel

I upgraded Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04 LTS immediately after its release (april 2012). Since then updates (new kernels and others) succeeded regularly, but recently, suddenly, updates fail consistently.

What causes the problem and how can it be solved?

Terminal information after the last update attempt:

```
ariel@ariel-MS-7592:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Setting up linux-image-3.2.0-26-generic (3.2.0-26.41) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.2.0-26-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-26-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.2.0-26-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-26-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-26-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.2.0-26-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-26-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.2.0-26-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-26-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.2.0-26-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-26-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 11: /etc/default/grub: splash”: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.2.0-26-generic.postinst line 1010.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.2.0-26-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-3.2.0-26-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.2.0-26-generic is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 3.2.0.26.28); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfiguredNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                         No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.2.0-26-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 11: /etc/default/grub: splash”: not found
```

It looks like you might have a typo in /etc/default/grub?

You need to edit the file with

```
sudoedit /etc/default/grub
```

and then go to line 11 and replace the `”` with a `"`. Basically it looks like you edited the file and some editor put in one of those smart quotes instead of a normal `"` quote.

Then save the file and run `sudo update-grub` and then reboot; then try the upgrade again.

- Related bug report with a [similar problem](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1008390).

Comment: How can it be repaired? I apologize - Ubuntu for me is a "black box" functioning usually perfectly and demanding almost no knowledge from me.

Comment: Thank you very much Jorge. I did as you wrote, then I tried to find updates using the update manager but there were none. Do I have to recover all the failed updates (how is it done?), or it will be done automatically? Now I am waiting to the next update hoping that the problem is indeed overcome. I'll report,of course.

Comment: The updates won't fix anything. You need to fix the file to replace the weird quotation mark with a " Once that's done the next updates should work fine.

Comment: Thanks Jorge. I appreciate very much your help.  The problem seems to be  solved.  Finally a new update succeeded today.